# Swift pagecontroller storyboard UI object connect with UIPageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have done pageviewcontroller within container view I can able to show page control by using programmatic but my container view I did by using storyboard, so I don't know how to show the page controller inside container center. So, I used storyboard page controller ui object drag and drop it now how to connect with my page view controller methods and how to make dot's moving by using pageviewcontroller image array count.

```
func configurePageControl() {
        // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
        //pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: self.containerview.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.containerview.frame.size.height - 50,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))

        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageTitles.count
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        //self.containerview.addSubview(pageControl)
    }

    // MARK: Delegate functions
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0]
        //self.pageControl.currentPage = pageTitles.index(of: pageContentViewController)!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

if let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?[0] {
    guard let index = arrayVCs.index(of: viewController) else {
        return
    }
    //you can find index here..
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index
}
}
```

**Update**

```
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{
    if (!completed) {
        self.pageControl.currentPage = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first!.view.tag //

    }
}
```

> Set tags to your viewcontrollers view.

Comment: I am getting Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'String'. at this line     guard let index = arrayVCs.index(of: viewController) else {
@Pratik Sodha

Comment: Value of type 'UIPageControl' has no member 'currentPageIndex'@Pratik Sodha

Comment: @stackflow use `currentPage` property of  `UIPageControl `. Ans edited.